# How can I scale a Bitmap in Android while maintaining the proportions?

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

I want to draw a human body using a `Bitmap` for each body part (because I will apply different color filters and effects to each part).

So I drew a body in Photoshop, divided it into parts and saved each one into a separate file with background transparent and all of them with the same dimensions. Therefore if i draw  one by one in a view over each other the final result *should be* the whole body as it was before cutting the parts out.

But I do not know how to manage the possible scaling of the view that the layout could make to maintaining the relative position of each body part and achieve a perfect representation of a human body.

Comment: Provide a screenshot of what you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scale a Bitmap you can use this function:

```
        Bitmap scaledBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBmp, int finalWidth, int finalHeight, false);
```

This function will scale "originalBmp" to finalWidth and finalHeight.
If you want to keep the propotions replace finalWidth with "originalBmp.getWidth()*0.8", that would make the bitmap 20% smaller (also do it with the Height).